# Inserir registro do banco em colunas do DataGridView em C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou com um problema: Pois tenho um `DataGridView1` e quando eu ler os registros do banco de dados cada linha deverá ser adicionado em uma `Column` do meu `DataGridView1`. Exemplo meu  `DataGridView1` tem as colunas `Column1, Column2, ... Column10` e ao varrer o banco tenho os registros: `1,2,3 ... 20` no qual o `DataGridView1` deveria ficar alimentado como na imagem abaixo, alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta seria minha tabela no banco de dados onde eu já faço uma consulta e obtenho o valor da coluna `FICCOD` faço a conversão para inteiro e depois adiciono no grid!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou fazendo é este abaixo mais em algumas situações ele não alimenta todos os registros do banco, se por exemplo eu tiver 15 registros ele alimentará somente os os 10 primeiros, só estar dando certo se no banco estiver uma quantidade de registros que possam ser divididos em intervalos de 10 registros "fechados".

```
private void alimentaGrid()
{           
    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Clear();

    DataSet ds = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT FICCOD FROM FICHA");
    int contador = 0;

    ArrayList ListaMesa = new ArrayList();

    foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {               
        Int64 codigo = Int64.Parse(row["FICCOD"].ToString().Trim());

        ListaMesa.Add(codigo);  
        contador += 1;

        if(contador.Equals(10))
        {
            string Column1 = String.Empty;
            string Column2 = String.Empty;
            string Column3 = String.Empty;
            string Column4 = String.Empty;
            string Column5 = String.Empty;
            string Column6 = String.Empty;
            string Column7 = String.Empty;
            string Column8 = String.Empty;
            string Column9 = String.Empty;
            string Column10 = String.Empty;

            for(int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
            {
                Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                Column7 = ListaMesa[6].ToString().Trim();
                Column8 = ListaMesa[7].ToString().Trim();
                Column9 = ListaMesa[8].ToString().Trim();
                Column10 = ListaMesa[9].ToString().Trim();
            }

            DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10);

            ListaMesa.Clear();
            contador = 0;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu queres trocar as linhas e colunas isso? Digo, transformar as linhas (registros) em colunas e as colunas em linhas?

Comment: Seria basicamente isso mesmo, como estar na imagem o valor de cada coluna corresponde a uma linha no banco de dados.

Comment: Você teria um exemplo do banco de dados seu ai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver meu problema da seguinte forma como estar logo abaixo, sei que ficou uma pequena gambiara :(

Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão melhor eu agradeço!

```
private void alimentaGrid()
{
    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Clear();

    DataSet ds = Engebuilder.Library.LDataAccess.GetDataSet("SELECT FICCOD FROM FICHA");
    int contador = 0;
    int aux = 0;
    int QtdTotal = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    int resto = QtdTotal;

    ArrayList ListaMesa = new ArrayList();

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Int64 codigo = Int64.Parse(row["FICCOD"].ToString().Trim());

        ListaMesa.Add(codigo);
        contador += 1;

        if (resto >= 10)
        {
            if (contador.Equals(10))
            {
                string Column1 = String.Empty;
                string Column2 = String.Empty;
                string Column3 = String.Empty;
                string Column4 = String.Empty;
                string Column5 = String.Empty;
                string Column6 = String.Empty;
                string Column7 = String.Empty;
                string Column8 = String.Empty;
                string Column9 = String.Empty;
                string Column10 = String.Empty;

                for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                {
                    Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                    Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                    Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                    Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                    Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                    Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                    Column7 = ListaMesa[6].ToString().Trim();
                    Column8 = ListaMesa[7].ToString().Trim();
                    Column9 = ListaMesa[8].ToString().Trim();
                    Column10 = ListaMesa[9].ToString().Trim();
                }

                DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10);

                ListaMesa.Clear();
                contador = 0;
                aux += 1;

                resto = (QtdTotal - (10 * aux));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (resto)
            {
                case 9:
                if (contador.Equals(9))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;
                    string Column5 = String.Empty;
                    string Column6 = String.Empty;
                    string Column7 = String.Empty;
                    string Column8 = String.Empty;
                    string Column9 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                        Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                        Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                        Column7 = ListaMesa[6].ToString().Trim();
                        Column8 = ListaMesa[7].ToString().Trim();
                        Column9 = ListaMesa[8].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 9);
                }
                break;

                case 8:
                if (contador.Equals(8))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;
                    string Column5 = String.Empty;
                    string Column6 = String.Empty;
                    string Column7 = String.Empty;
                    string Column8 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                        Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                        Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                        Column7 = ListaMesa[6].ToString().Trim();
                        Column8 = ListaMesa[7].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 8);
                }
                break;

                case 7:
                if (contador.Equals(7))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;
                    string Column5 = String.Empty;
                    string Column6 = String.Empty;
                    string Column7 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                        Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                        Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                        Column7 = ListaMesa[6].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 7);
                }
                break;

                case 6:
                if (contador.Equals(6))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;
                    string Column5 = String.Empty;
                    string Column6 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                        Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                        Column6 = ListaMesa[5].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 6);
                }
                break;

                case 5:
                if (contador.Equals(5))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;
                    string Column5 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                        Column5 = ListaMesa[4].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 5);
                }
                break;

                case 4:
                if (contador.Equals(4))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;
                    string Column4 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                        Column4 = ListaMesa[3].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 4);
                }
                break;

                case 3:
                if (contador.Equals(3))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;
                    string Column3 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                        Column3 = ListaMesa[2].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2, Column3);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 3);
                }
                break;

                case 2:
                if (contador.Equals(2))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;
                    string Column2 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                        Column2 = ListaMesa[1].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1, Column2);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 2);
                }
                break;

                case 1:
                if (contador.Equals(1))
                {
                    string Column1 = String.Empty;

                    for (int i = 0; i < ListaMesa.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Column1 = ListaMesa[0].ToString().Trim();
                    }

                    DataGridViewListaMesa.Rows.Add(Column1);

                    ListaMesa.Clear();
                    contador = 0;

                    resto = (resto - 1);
                }
                break;

                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```